# How can I force SQLite database actions to be synchronous

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I'm trying to update the schema of a table in my SQLite database during the onUpgrade() method. I'm doing thing by deleting the table and then recreating it with the new schema. Sometimes the old schema persists after these two actions are run, so I need a way to force the old table to be deleted before creating the new table. Does anyone know how to do this? Here is the code:

```
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARMS);
        database.execSQL(buildAlarmTable());
```

OLD SCHEMA:

```
private String buildAlarmTable() {
    return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARMS +
            "(" + KEY_ALARM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            KEY_ALARM_NAME + " TEXT," +
            KEY_ALARM_TIME + " INTEGER" +
            ")";
}
```

NEW SCHEMA:

```
public String buildAlarmTable() {
    return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARMS +
            "(" + KEY_ALARM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            KEY_ALARM_NAME + " TEXT," +
            KEY_ALARM_TIME + " INTEGER," +
            KEY_ALARM_MALID + " INTEGER" +
            ")";
}
```

I know the old schema persists because I am getting an exception that the "KEY_ALARM_MALID" column doesn't exist when reading from the database later on.

Comment: Typically, you just update the database version number in your SqliteOpenHelper class

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for synchronous actions for, though. The IO operation for querying a SQLite database is fairly synchronous

Comment: To clarify, sometimes the newly created TABLE_ALARMS table will have the old schema, which doesn't have the new column. Other times it will correctly have the new schema. This lead me to think the actions aren't happening synchronously

Comment: I read the question, and I understand the problem, however, I am not sure why that would happen if you have upgraded the database version (which you should always do after modifying the schema)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the table and re-creating it `onUpgrade()` is not the ideal way to update the table's schema. Plus you will lose all the rows of data! Use `ALTER TABLE` like this, assuming the old version is 1 and the new version is 2.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_ALARM_MALID + " int default 0;");
    }
}
```

And of course, keep the new version of `buildAlarmTable()` for new databases.

But if you must drop the table, try this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARMS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```